# How to increase the zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have developed a responsive website with big pictures ( 30000x30000px ) and I need a way ( with css, html or javascript ) to increase the zoom.

I have used this meta below but I still need to increase the zoom.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1000">
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: why not manually scale the elements you want - you can't control the browser's zoom

Comment: Change the initial-scale value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: this question proves a lack of search, anyway change the initial-scale or use the css zoom on the html tag

Comment: Is there something stopping the user from just zooming using pinch on the screen?

Comment: Gustav: Yes, there is a limit with the zoom.
ScottMarcus: I have changed the inizial-scale to 10 but then the zoom doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Ryad.iv: changed the initial-scale and zoom but doesn't work. I am using Android 6 with the latest chrome.

Comment: @xRobot as you I told you can always zoom with this css property https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom

Comment: @Ryad.iv but I need a way to increase the zoom manually.

Comment: what do you mean by manually ?

Comment: @Ryad.iv with the "pinch to zoom". If I use the zoom css rule, then it only shows a bigger image.

Comment: *it only shows a bigger image* What's supposed to happen instead? Can you clarify what you're trying to do?